# Group datagrid entries by hidden property

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, grouping

I have the following data structure:

```
public class TimeData
{
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
    public IList<WorkTime> WorkTimes { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public ObservableCollection<TimeData> TimeDatas { get; set; }
```

In my datagrid I want to display all Worktimes. Grouped by Employee.
Like this:

Date | Hours | TimeCode

Jon Doe

12/03/19 | 8 | 433

13/03/19 | 8 | 433

14/03/19 | 5 | 546

Mike Muster

12/03/19 | 4 | 653

13/03/19 | 3 | 433

14/03/19 | 9 | 546

```
public class Employee
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
public class WorkTime
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public double Hours { get; set; }
    public string TimeCode { get; set; }
}
```

I already tried the following code:

```
ListCollectionView collectionView = new ListCollectionView(this.viewModel.TimeDatas);
collectionView.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Employee"));
this.grdTimeData.ItemsSource = collectionView;
```

This groups by employee, but doesn't show the list of WorkTimes:
[image: Incorrect Datagrid]
In the grid rows, I only need the WorkTimes, the Employee only for grouping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to transform your data into a format that the `DataGrid` can handle. Create a view model class that contains all properties:

```
public class EmployeeAndWorkTime
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public double Hours { get; set; }
    public string TimeCode { get; set; }
}
```

...and bind to an `IEnumerable<EmployeeAndWorkTime>` that you create from your existing `TimeDatas` collection:

```
TransformedTimeDatas = TimeDatas.Select(timeData =>
{
    EmployeeAndWorkTime[] viewModels = new EmployeeAndWorkTime[timeData.WorkTimes.Count];
    for (int i = 0; i < timeData.WorkTimes.Count; ++i)
        viewModels[i] = new EmployeeAndWorkTime()
        {
            Name = string.Format("{0} {1}", timeData.Employee.FirstName, timeData.Employee.LastName),
            Date = timeData.WorkTimes[i].Date,
            Hours = timeData.WorkTimes[i].Hours,
            TimeCode = timeData.WorkTimes[i].TimeCode
        };
    return viewModels;
}).ToArray();

ListCollectionView collectionView = new ListCollectionView(TransformedTimeDatas);
collectionView.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription("Name"));
this.grdTimeData.ItemsSource = collectionView;
```